How can I call constructor with less parameters with no assignment of default value to a class variable in Java?
public class Sample {
    
    int id;    
    String name;
    int age;

    Sample(int i, String n){
        id = i;
        name = n;
    }

    Sample(int i, String n, int a){
        id = i;
        name = n;
        age=a;
    }

    void display(){
        System.out.println(id+" "+name+" "+age);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Sample s1 = new Sample(111,"Karan");
        Sample s2 = new Sample(222,"Aryan",25);
        s1.display();
        s2.display();
    }
}

Output:
111 Karan 0
222 Aryan 25

When I am initializing new Sample(111,"Karan"), I want Sample(int i, String n) to be called so that my output should be 111 Karan i.e. I don't want 'age' to get assigned with any value.
i.e. Expected output:
111 Karan
222 Aryan 25


"I don't want 'age' to get assigned with any value." Well that's unfortunate, because all fields will have a value. If you don't want to assign a specific value to age, it'll have the default value for the type. (The default value for int is 0.) There are multiple options you could take here though. You could make age an Integer instead of an int, and use null to represent "unspecified" for example. Every field will have a value though - the value of age would be the null reference instead of a reference to an Integer value, that's all.

Use a ternary operator in your display string: void display() { System.out.println(id + ", " + name + (age == 0 ? "" : " " + age)); }.

Every Sample will always have a value for age.  There is no way around this.

What I would do is set age to -1 and use an if-statment in the display method.
Code
public class Sample {
    
    int id;    
    String name;
    int age;

    Sample(int i, String n){
        id = i;
        name = n;
        age = -1;
    }

    Sample(int i, String n, int a){
        id = i;
        name = n;
        age=a;
    }

    void display(){
        if(this.age == -1)
        {
            System.out.println(id + "\t" + name);  
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(id + "\t" + name + "\t" +age);        
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Sample s1 = new Sample(111,"Karan");
        Sample s2 = new Sample(222,"Aryan",25);
        s1.display();
        s2.display();
    }
}

Output
111 John
222 Kim 22


I appreciate your solution. But still not able to understand the significance of having a constructor with less parameters if we have another constructor with more parameters? I mean isn't Constructor overloading is getting failed over here ?

One big significance is, let's say, you have a constructor with 20 parameters and one with three. Would you want to use the constructor with 20 parameters or the constructor with three if only those three values were important for your application?

Don't overthink this. Constructor overloading in Java allows developers to define multiple constructors within a class, each with a distinct set of parameters. This powerful feature provides flexibility in object creation, enabling the selection of appropriate constructors based on different scenarios and input variations. From here.

Change
int age;

to be
Integer age;

Then you can legitimately assign null to it.
